# docker-compose php files are updated but not executed

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am in a weird condition with docker-compose that I cannot explain.

I have installed a docker-compose with three services to serve Symfony project. The services are `php-fpm`, `mysql` and `nginx`.

So far I have installed all properly, and the Symfony is running as expected, but, when I do a change on a `php` file on the `host` machine, and I refresh the browser, then the changes are not reflected on my browser.

At the same time, if run the commands `docker -it exec PHP-CONTAINER-ID sh` or `docker -it exec NGINX-CONTAINER-ID bash` and then in both scenarios execute the `more /srv/api/Serializer/SerializerContextBuilder.php` I can see the changes I did on my host machine in both sides *(`nginx` and `php-fpm`)*

I run the docker on an `Ubuntu 20.04` system.

Docker Version: `Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350`

Docker Compose Version: `docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192`

Any idea of what can make this issue? Is there anyone have experienced such a weird case and if so how solved it?